# How to detect Unicode character u+21b5 in angular?

Tags: angular

While parsing data from an http response, I ran across a special character '\u21b5' that looks like `↵`, is there a method that will detect this in Angular?

This is what my data looks like,

`["Title", "First", "Last", "Email", "↵"
,"Title", "First", "Last", "Email", "↵"
,"Title", "First", "Last", "Email"]`

Comment: Kindly explain what you have tried so far. Have you tried indexOf() method of searching index of perticular character from string.

Comment: i've tried `let s = this.csvData.indexOf('/\u21b5/', 5);` which returns -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular indexOf only takes a string parameter, no regular expressions.

```
const arr = ["Title", "First", "Last", "Email", "↵"];
arr.indexOf('\u21b5'); // 4
```

To use regular expressions, you habe to use the `find` method. Note that for Java-/Typescript to parse the unicode character in a regular expression, you need to use the `u` flag - [See also this](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/es6-unicode-regex), taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/280762/).

```
const char = arr.find(item => /\u{21b5}/u.test(item));
if (char) {
    result = arr.indexOf(char); // 4
}
```

You can also write a custom RegEx-enabled indexOf function:

```
function regExIndexOf(array: string[], term: RegExp, start = 0): number {
  let result = -1;
  array.forEach((item, index) => {
    if (result === -1 && index >= start && term.test(item)) {
      result = index;
    }
  });
  return result;
}

regExIndexOf(["Title", "First", "Last", "Email", "↵"], new RegExp('Title')); // 0
regExIndexOf(["Title", "First", "Last", "Email", "↵"], new RegExp('Title'), 1); // -1
regExIndexOf(["Title", "First", "Last", "Email", "↵"], new RegExp('\u{21b5}', 'u')); //4
```

[See on Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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)

Comment: the routine is making "term" parameter print /arrow/ and it changes by modifying '\u21b5' only proble is it still has these two arrows in the print /arrow/

Comment: it's the RegExp function causing those forward slashes.

Comment: I can't understand what exactly you mean with your second comment. Can you paste the code you used and the result? I've added a Typescript playground link to my answer that shows that this should work, you can also test there.

Comment: There was a small bug in the function that made it always return the index of the last matched item in the array, not the first. I've updated it to skip looking after a match has been found. It's probably still slower and can be optimized by using a for...of loop and the array.entries() function, but the version in the answer is still a good and legible start to understand this, imho.

Comment: i continue to test with my data that i provided and the code you provided, i still get -1, unfortunately. i think it's having to do something wiht 'unicode 21b5' i'm developing on osx.

Comment: `if (e.charCodeAt(0) === 10) { console.log( 'found one' ); }` , this solution let's me at least determine that it's a LF (line feed), so this is one way to work it out :)

Comment: while your answer didn't necessarily solve my problem, it lead to the solution i mentioned above ^ please put that on your post and i'll mark it as an answer.

Comment: ... The special character `\u21B5` - is that actually in the data or does it only show up in your notepad (or osx-equivalent)? The char with the char code `10` is a linefeed. It's unicode character escape sequence is `\u000A`. It's also often written as `\n`. So if you use `\n` or `\u{000A}` as the search term, it should work as designed.

Comment: To answer your question, it is actually in the data. Thank you